# How to match a named capturing group within an optional token?

Tags: .net, regex

I started with this regex containing the named capturing groups `EntityType`, `EntityName`, and `EntityId`:

```
EntityType=(?<EntityType>.+)&EntityName=(?<EntityName>.+)&EntityId=(?<EntityId>[\w-]+)
```

Each group matches against this text (note ampersand character in second example):

```
EntityType=FundingRnd&EntityName=ABC&EntityId=df78abcd-fb75-473d-a4bb-412a9d89215c
EntityType=FundingRnd&EntityName=ABC & XYZ&EntityId=df78abcd-fb75-473d-a4bb-412a9d89215c
```

Then I found that the last `EntityId` part had to be made optional, so I wrapped the EntityId part of the regex with `(` and `)?`:

```
EntityType=(?<EntityType>.+)&EntityName=(?<EntityName>.+)(&EntityId=(?<EntityId>[\w-]+))?
```

Now the `EntityId` group no longer matches against the same text.

I'm using the .NET Framework regex engine with the "ignore case" switch on. The testing tool is [this one](http://rad-software-regular-expression-designer.software.informer.com/1.4/) which uses the .NET engine under the hood.

Any ideas? The intention is to extract the text from each of these groups.

Comment: try `EntityType=(?<EntityType>.+)&EntityName=(?<EntityName>[^&]+)(&EntityId=(?<EntityId>[\w-]+))?` see it here: http://regex101.com/r/kI4tV3/1

Comment: @JorgeCampos Apologies, I didn't give a great example. The problem is that the value for EntityName can contain an ampersand.

Comment: hummm now it is a problem... see if i can figure it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` operator is greedy and combined with the dot causes the matches to shoot to the end of the string and backtrack, you wouldn't be able to use a non-greedy `+?` quantifier either because of the optional group at the end so I would consider using negation.

```
EntityType=(?<EntityType>[^&]+)&EntityName=(?<EntityName>(?:(?!&EntityId).)+)(?:&EntityId=(?<EntityId>[\w-]+))?
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iE4eT2/2)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't give a great example. The problem is that the value for EntityName can contain an ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

I try this regex take if necessary.

```
EntityType=((?:(?!(?:EntityType|EntityName|EntityId|&)).)*)\&EntityName=((?:(?!(?:EntityType|EntityName|EntityId)).)*)\&EntityId=((?:(?!(?:EntityType|EntityName|EntityId|&)).)*)
```

**SEE DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/fM1mC8/2